# Docker Add every file in current directory

Tags: docker

I have a simple web application that I would like to place in a docker container.   The angular application exists in the `frontend/` folder, which is withing the `application/` folder.

When the Dockerfile is in the `application/` folder and  reads as follows:

```
FROM node
ADD frontend/ frontend/
RUN (cd frontend/; npm install;)
CMD (cd frontend/; npm start;)
```

everything runs correctly.

However, when I move the Dockerfile into the `frontend/` folder and change it to read

```
FROM node
ADD . frontend/
RUN (cd frontend/; npm install;)
CMD (cd frontend/; npm start;)
```

no files are copied and the project does not run.

How can I add every file and folder recursively in the current directory to my docker image?

Comment: What about changing the source to ./

Comment: `ADD` `.` `/` `./` all copy the current build context contents for me.  What does your `docker build` command look like?

Comment: @Matt no luck with `ADD . / ./`, and my build command is `sudo docker build -t testfrontend .` in the frontend folder

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Dockerfile that ended up working was

```
FROM node
ADD . / frontend/
RUN (cd frontend/; npm install;)
CMD (cd frontend/; npm start;)
```

Shoutout to @Matt for the lead on `. / ./`, but I think the only reason that didn't work was because for some reason my application will only run when it is inside a directory, not in the 'root'.  This might have something to do with @VonC's observation that the node image doesn't have a WORKDIR.

Comment: Good feedback and more precise than my answer. +1. Did you try with a `WORKDIR /`?

Answer (score 1):

First, try `COPY` just to test if the issue persists.

Second, make sure that no files are copied by changing your `CMD` to a `ls frontend`

I do not see a `WORKDIR` in [`node/7.5/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/90d5e3df903b830d039d3fe8f30e3a62395db37e/7.5/Dockerfile), so `frontend` could be in `/frontend`: check `ls /frontend` too.