# Docker image creation throwing "no such file or directory, access '/node_modules/sails'" when dockerizing a sails.js app

Tags: node.js, docker, sails.js

Below is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

RUN npm install -g sails@0.12.13

ADD . / ./
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 80

CMD (sails lift)
```

Image creation fails with following log:

```
ending build context to Docker daemon  70.03MB
Step 1/6 : FROM node:latest
 ---> 60bea5b86079
Step 2/6 : RUN npm install -g sails@0.12.13
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3f3c7fcdb090
Step 3/6 : ADD . / ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 78700b41cf26
Step 4/6 : RUN (npm install)
 ---> Running in d49423611a77
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.4.0
npm info lifecycle ecs-notification@0.0.0~preinstall: ecs-notification@0.0.0
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /node_modules/sails
npm ERR! path /node_modules/sails
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/node_modules/sails'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-09-08T13_00_06_956Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c (npm install)' returned a non-zero code: 254
```

Even if I try to create the directory, or change the permission to 777 using:
`RUN (mkdir -p /node_modules/sails; chmod 777 /node_modules/sails)`

it still fails with the same error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  70.03MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:latest
 ---> 60bea5b86079
Step 2/7 : RUN npm install -g sails@0.12.13
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3f3c7fcdb090
Step 3/7 : RUN (mkdir -p /node_modules/sails; chmod 777 /node_modules/sails)
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c7f1784c24c8
Step 4/7 : ADD . / ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 334017659dde
Step 5/7 : RUN (npm install)
 ---> Running in 833e3ef6a010
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.4.0
npm info lifecycle ecs-notification@0.0.0~preinstall: ecs-notification@0.0.0
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /node_modules/sails
npm ERR! path /node_modules/sails
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/node_modules/sails'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-09-08T13_13_55_258Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c (npm install)' returned a non-zero code: 254
```

Docker version: 17.06.2-ce-mac27 (19124)

Any pointers around how I can debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Dockerfile to below

```
FROM node:latest

RUN npm install -g sails@0.12.13
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./

EXPOSE 80

CMD sails lift
```

You should only copy `package.json` first and the do npm install and then copy code. Also your `ADD` statement was wrong. There was an extra space

Next make sure you have `.dockerignore` which ignores the node_modules. Else node_modules will be overwritten by the copy operation

Comment: Thanks! The `ADD` statement is probably correct. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238935/docker-add-every-file-in-current-directory

Comment: @amit_saxena, Thanks for pointing it out, will have to check the behavior of the same and understand what it does.